# $_FILES doesn't catch file

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a problem uploading a file to my server... Here is my form:

```
<form action="./status/UploadStatus.php" method="POST" id="PhotoPost">
<textarea style="width: 100%;" rows="5" placeholder="Geef commentaar bij je foto..." name="data"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="media" size="50" accept="Image/*">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="p">
<input type="hidden" name="owner" value="<?php echo $u;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="author" value="<?php echo $log_username;?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload!" id="UploadStatus">
</form>
```

And my UploadStatus.php is like this:

```
...
$name = $_FILES['media']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
$ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

But somehow, it doesn't catch the file name or any other stuff of the uploaded file... Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to write in form field `enctype=multipart/form-data1`

Comment: More info on multipart form data http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4